# Lock screen but keep Google Maps turn-by-turn navigation and GPS active

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, lock-screens, google-maps-navigation

I've a Sony Xperia Z with Android 4.2.2 and need to lock my screen but keep the (voice/turn-byturn) navigation active. How can I achieve that?

As it's currently, as soon as I lock the screen, GPS seems to be disabled instantely (at least when I unlock the phone, it needs to reaquire a GPS fix) and turn-by-turn navigation in Google Maps is instantly disabled.

How can I keep both things activated?

Background: I want to travel by bike without needing to look at my smartphone every few crossroads. Since I don't have a handlebar mount for my smartphone I've to keep it in one of the pockets of my pants. For some reason (I guess the fabric is too thin) the phone registers touches all the time, leading to 'butt-dials' and similiar things.

Comment: are you using `Extend standby mode` or `power saving mode` this will turn off gps when screen is locked

Comment: not as far as I can tell. I checked energy settings and only 'power saving mode' is active which should only take effect if battery state is less than 30% (which it isn't). Also 'Disable GPS' is unchecked as is 'Disable mobile data'.

Comment: Can you disable power saving mode and check

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: @sameer sorry for the delay but I had to bicycle home (18km and I'm not very...fit, which is currently changing) before I could post again. So, yes it worked. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as 'the' answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Power saving mode will disable the gps when the screen is locked. Disable power saving mode in settings.